# Import xml in React/Express project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm totally new in React and Express. I have to make a project for Friday for school. Please help me to solve the problem.
I want to import xml file to React app. It works only on React project. When i put it into React and Express project from the internet i got error that
GEThttp://localhost:8081/assets/dzietnosc.xml [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 16ms]

As I said previously, it works only on clean React project. Should I do an endpoint on Express and there read xml?

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';
import TabelaDzietnosci from './TabelaDzietnosci';

class ImportXML extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: [],
            year: "",
            value: "",
            tablica: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //get data request
        axios.get('../../assets/dzietnosc.xml', {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
        }).then(res => {
            //Storing users detail in state array object
            //Tu pobiera xml i zapisuje do zmiennej name
            const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(res.data);
            this.setState({ name: jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName('field') })
        });
    }

    render() {
        
        var table = []
        return <div>
            {(
                this.state.name.map((item, index) => {
                    var trigger = false
                    if (item.attributes['name'] === 'Year') {
                        this.setState({
                            year: this.state.year = item.value
                        })
                    } if (item.attributes['name'] === "Value") {
                        this.setState({
                            value: this.state.value = item.value
                        })
                        trigger = true
                    }
                    if (trigger) {
                        table.push({ "year": this.state.year, "value": this.state.value })
                        trigger = false

                    } this.setState({
                        value: this.state.tablica = table
                    })
                }

                )

            )

            }
            <TabelaDzietnosci dane={this.state.tablica}/>
        </div>
    }
}

export default ImportXML
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';



class TabelaDzietnosci extends Component {
    render() {
        var labels = this.props.dane.map(function(e){
            return e.year
        })
        var values = this.props.dane.map(function(e){
            return e.value
        })

   

        return (
          
            <div>
                <h4>Współczynnik dzietności</h4>
                <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.dane)}</p>
                {labels + values}
            

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TabelaDzietnosci
```

Comment: React and specifically `axios.get('../../assets/dzietnosc.xml', ...` is client-side code, it runs inside the browser. It has no direct access to the hard drive. Which means while you're using project folder paths when importing other components, you cannot do the same inside your components. Copy the asset folder inside the build folder, then use `axios.get('assets/dzietnosc.xml', ...`. You should learn to use the dev tools for debugging, they have a console tab where you can inspect the xhrs made by axios.

Comment: Now i got error 
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
ImportXML@http://localhost:8081/static/js/bundle.js:1411:5
Routes@http://localhost:8081/static/js/bundle.js:330045:7
div

Comment: Yes, you're calling this.setState inside your render method but you're not supposed to do that. Updating the state causes re-rendering, and if you update the state during rendering, you're creating an infinite loop. Do all the restructuring right after loading the data, then set the new state once. render() is only supposed to *display* the current state, not change it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I put everything inside ComponentDidMount and now it's ok :)